# Trying to find word count in a text file using a different text file as "dictionary"

Tags: python, string, text, count

I have a vocabulary file that contains words I need to find in other text documents.  I need to find how many of each word is found, if any.  For example:

vocabulary.txt:

```
thought
await
thorough
away
red
```

test.txt:

```
I thought that if i await thorough enough, my thought would take me away.
Away I thought the thought.
```

In the end, I should see that there is 4 instances of thought, 1 await, 2 away, 1 thorough, and 0 red.  I've tried it this way:

```
for vocabLine in vocabOutFile:
    wordCounter = 0
    print >> sys.stderr, "Vocab word:", vocabLine
    for line in testFile:
        print >> sys.stderr, "Line 1 :", line
        if vocabLine.rstrip('\r\n') in line.rstrip('\r\n'):
            print >> sys.stderr, "Vocab word is in line"
            wordCounter = wordCounter + line.count(vocabLine)
            print >> sys.stderr, "Word counter", wordCounter
    testFile.seek(0, 0)
```

I have a strange feeling that because of the return characters in the vocab file it isn't recognizing the words in the file, because during debugging I determined that it was counting properly any words that were on the end of the string that matched.  However, after using rstrip() the count still doesn't count correctly.  After all this is done, I have to remove words from the vocab list that don't occur more than 2 times.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `testFile` a file object?

Comment: Yes, testFile and vocabOutFile are both file objects

Comment: Is "Away" supposed to be counted? Looks like it is. You should normalise the case (eg call `.lower()` on the strings) somewhere

Comment: So what output _do_ you get?

Comment: After the first pass, testFile will be at the end, so that loop will be skipped on subsequent passes. You'll need to reopen the file or seek back to the beginning

Comment: It recognizes that the word is within the line, but unless the word is at the END of the line, the counter doesn't count it. It remains 0.  If it is at the end of the line, the counter is 1.

Comment: Yes, I have a SEEK statement after that testFile loop ends, it just isn't placed correctly here for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to make a dictionary of your vocab words.

```
vocab_counter = {vocabLine.strip().lower(): 0 for vocabLine in vocabOutFile}
```

Then scan testFile just once (which is more efficient) incrementing the count for each word

```
for line in testFile:
    for word in re.findall(r'\w+', line.lower()):
        if word in vocab_counter:
            vocab_counter[word] += 1
```

Comment: Hey there, I don't know if you're still watching this, but the compiler has a syntax problem with the segment: vocabLine.strip().lower(): 0 for vocabLine in vocabOutFile

It doesn't like the for statement for some reason

Comment: @FeralShadow, That is a dict comprehension. It only works on Python2.7 or higher. For Python2.6 you can use dict((vocabLine.strip().lower(), 0) for vocabLine in vocabOutFile)

Comment: Aha ok!  Strange how I don't have 2.7.  Thanks!

Comment: So, one more issue: It's not incrementing the count for any of the words.  It's acting like it doesn't find the word within the dict.  It reads each line correctly, and looks at each word properly within the second FOR loop, but the IF statement is never true.

Comment: Ah! Sorry I missed some of the code you provided. it works perfectly! Thank you gnibbler!

Answer (score 2):

Using `regex` and `collections.Counter`

```
import re
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

with open("voc") as v, open("test") as test:
    #create a set of words from vocabulary file
    words = set(line.strip().lower() for line in v) 

    #find words in test file using regex
    words_test = [ re.findall(r'\w+', line) for line in test ]

    #Create counter of words that are found in words set from vocab file
    counter = Counter(word.lower()  for word in chain(*words_test)\
                                          if word.lower() in words)
    for word in words:
        print word, counter[word]
```

**output**

```
thought 4
away 2
await 1
red 0
thorough 1
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but there's quite a bit of more advanced Python going on here (list comprehensions, itertools.chain, generator, *args) and it would probably be good to explain a little bit more how each of your lines of code are working.